# unable to Read file from network path in threads

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, c#-4.0, iis, file-io

I am unable to Read file from network path when i surround my code in threads. code work fine without threads. 
if i use threads and use local drive path (same system) then it work fine in threads as well but thats not an option for me. i have to access network file.

while accessing network file File.exsists return false. This dll is used in a webapplication developed using C#, ASP.NET v4.xxx

I am using IIS webserver.

Comment: That's probably an impersonation issue.  Please show us your code.

Comment: Just *how* does it work locally?  Does it work in IIS locally? Or are you using IIS locally?

Comment: but if we access without threads -- same file path -- it works fine

Comment: locally means if we give local drive path like D:\ drive path drive on same server -- but if we use network path like \\server2\folder it only works when are not using threads. with threads file.exists return false. IIS is installed on remote server

Comment: So if we use multiple threads do we need to impersonate in each thread or impersonation work for whole application?